# strange aapt.exe error while adding item to xml file

Tags: android, xml, aapt

Why do I get an `aapt.exe has stopped working` error when I put this code  in my `res/menu/menu.xml` file? *by the way, this comes directly from android developer website*

XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I would like to have the search button always visible and I would like to have the settings button? I want 2 or more items in the xml, which I can't do.

Comment: No. Don't worry. It happens, sometimes. Just clear the error and run the project. You will see this kind of joke many times.

Comment: i can't clean my project (and it doent auto generate the R.java file), and everytime i save i get the aapt.exe error...

Comment: hello. Do you have any other errors reported by aapt during compile?

Comment: So, you must have some problem in some xml files. Check them ALL, from Manifest to strings, whatever xml file you have. But also try a restart SOMETIMES it fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I didn't have the icon.
Unfortunately, eclipse and android doesn't have a clear and intuitive way of letting you know where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I modified the menu resource. 
The problem seems to occur when we remove action_settings item from the menu and the corresponding string resource.
I re-introduced both the resources as below and the problem went away.
in menu/main.xml:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

 </menu>
```

in res/strings.xml

```
 <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

If you dont need that item in menu, you could just add the tag:

```
  android:visible="false"
```

It appeares to be some kind of problem with the R.java file which contained a reference
to action_settings even when it was removed, thereby causing the crash.